# Ubuntu does not detect external monitor properly

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors

I have a Lenovo T530 laptop. When I connect an external moniter, it detects moniter for a second and then does not detect. The screen is detected then lost repeatedly so both displays keep blinking on and off.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: What drivers are you running? Do you have the T530 with the optimus nvidia or only integrated gfx?